# Is User Input Possible in PDDL

Tags: artificial-intelligence, user-input, workspace, planning, pddl

I am using PDDL to define a path for a robot. The idea is that the robot should move 'x' no. of items from a room to outside the house . The variable "x" depends on the room. The robot should start from one room which the user tells has x no. of items. After transferring all the items it should move to next room and then the user tells how many items are there. The chain continues like this until all the rooms are emptied. The total no. rooms are finite but unknown.

I wanted to ask is there a way to give user inputs in pddl? 
I am using the following example to build my code. In the mentioned code the no. of rooms and items are already initialized which is not the case in my workspace.

http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~sheila/2542/w09/A1/introtopddl2.pdf

Answer (score 2):

In short, no that's not possible. You could perhaps have a higher-level executive that queries, and then creates a subproblem that can be solved with a planner. It's unclear if you'd really need a planner at that point, though.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a program that calls your planner and generates PDDL on-the-fly. In that program you elicit the user input, and then add the particular room *x* as part of the goal definition in your generated PDDL. This you then pass to the planner, possibly via writing it to a file (depending on how you interface with the planner).

See this paper for a related problem where an off-the-shelf planner is integrated into a game: Bartheye, Olivier and Eric Jacopin (2008) [*Connecting PDDL-based off-the-shelf planners to an arcade game*](http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~jorkin/bartheye_jacopin_ai_and_games_ecai_2008.pdf)